# Склеивание строк в одну и вывод через массив

Tags: c, строки

В чем моя ошибка склеивания строк и вывод потом ее сохранив в массив?
можете подсказать как сделать удобнее и легче?

```
#define M 30
#define N 100
int main()
{
char s[N], name[N], town[N],newage[N];
char array[M][N], n;
int age, i, age2;
for (n = 0; n < M && s[0] != '\n'; ++n)
{
    fgets(s, N, stdin);
    sscanf_s(s, "%100s  %d %100s", name,100, &age, town,100);
    age2 = 2017 - age;
    _itoa(age, newage,10);
    char *finally = NULL;
    strncat(finally,name);
    strncat(finally, newage);
    strncat(finally, town);
    strcpy(array[n], finally);

}
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}

getchar();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `man asprintf`, только потом не забудьте `free()` вызвать.

Comment: а как он работает?

Comment: `asprintf()` вначале считывает строку формата и аргументы и пытается выяснить сколько памяти она займёт, потом аллоциоует память и печатает в неё согласно формату. Если память не нужно аллоцировать, то всё сводится к простому вызову `snprintf()`. То, что вам привели ниже в качестве примера, лишь первый шаг по упрощению и очистке программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже это предложение цикла

```
for (n = 0; n < M && s[0] != '\n'; ++n)
```

имеет неопределенное поведение, так как символьный массив `s` не иниицализирован, а потому объект `s[0]` имеет неопределенное значение.

В данном фрагменте

```
age2 = 2017 - age;
_itoa(age, newage,10);
      ^^^
```

я думаю, вы собираетесь на самом деле преобразовать `age2` в строку, а не `age`. Иначе, какой смысл вычисления значения `age2`?

Данные предложения

```
char *finally = NULL;
strncat(finally,name);
strncat(finally, newage);
strncat(finally, town);
strcpy(array[n], finally);
```

также имеют неопределенное поведение, так как указатель `finally` имеет значение NULL, то есть не указывает на корректно выделенную память.

Нет никакой необходимости использовать этот указатель. Почему бы сразу же не писать в массив `array[n]`? Также стандартная C функция `strncat` требует задания трех аргументов, а не двух.

Кроме того, если было введено `n` строк, то в этом цикле

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

условие должны быть задано как

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ^^^^^
```

Первый цикл `for` можно записать следующим образом

```
size_t n = 0;
for ( ; n < M && fgets( s, N, stdin ) != NULL && s[0] != '\n'; ++n )
{
    sscanf_s( s, "%s  %d %s", name, N, &age, town, N );

    age = 2017 - age;
    _itoa(age, newage, 10);

    strcpy( array[n], name );
    strcat( array[n], newage );
    strcat( array[n], town );
}
```

Только в этом случае все слова в строке будут записаны слитно. Если хотите, чтобы они были записаны раздельно, то нужно добавлять пробелы между словами. Например,

```
    strcpy( array[n], name );
    strcat( array[n], " " );
    strcat( array[n], newage );
    strcat( array[n], " " );
    strcat( array[n], town );
```

Comment: n-1 так как после ввода нулевой строки я прекрощаю ввод строк, и что бы не вывадило 2 раза подряд одно и тоже поставил n-1

Comment: Поясните как name newage и town склеить и вывести пожалуйста уже 2 неделю не могу сделать(

Comment: @PaulFawkes Я уже указал, что у вас условие цикла задано не верно.

Comment: но у меня все отлично работает но я склеить не могу

Comment: вы сказали "почему сразу не писать в массив array[n]" как мне это сделать?

Comment: @PaulFawkes Я не знаю, как у вас "все отлично работает", когда код не должен компилироваться, так как функция strncat, ожидает три аргумента, а не два.

Comment: Нет, через strncat не работает! Но я попытался через strcpy все сохранить в массив array[n] но у меня сохраняется только последнее вводимое значение, как это исправить?

Comment: @PaulFawkes Я вам в ответе уже все написал.

Comment: ооо, вижу огромное спасибо! теперь все ясно

Comment: `snprintf()` не судьба применить? `_itoa()` -- это какое-то непереносимое нечто. `strtoul()` -- наше всё.

Comment: @0andriy _itoa и strtoul - это противоположные по действию функции.

Comment: Тем более. `snprintf()`.